# Function to define yearly intervals on big data frame in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, dataframe, apply

I'm working on a big data frame in order to prepare this data frame for a Boosted Regression Tree Model project.
Since I'm new to R and programming in general I'm stuck at a point of data preparation.
I've done hours of thinking on this problem and know how I would like to do it. I just can't do it in R.
My data frame basically looks like this:

`start.date` and `end.date` indicate a time interval that a company (e.g. `C1`) has been a customer of my potential company. Company 1 was a customer from 01/01/2009 to 31/12/2009, as well as in the next two years. The variable `amount.x` is the amount that was paid to be customer of my company.

```
> df <- data.frame(company,start.date,end.date,amount.x)
> df

      company start.date   end.date amount.x
    1      C1 01/01/2009 31/12/2009       10
    2      C1 01/01/2010 31/12/2010       20
    3      C1 01/01/2011 31/12/2011        5
    4      C2 01/01/2009 31/12/2009        7
    5      C2 01/01/2010 31/12/2010       12
    6      C2 01/01/2011 31/12/2011       11
```

What I'm trying to do is to add a new column showing how many years different companies have been customers of my company.
The problem is that the time interval between `start.date` and `end.date` is not always exactly one year. Sometimes companies have been a customer for a month, but this should still be displayed as 1 year as a customer.
It should look like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(company,start.date,end.date,amount.x,Years.as.customer)
> df
      company start.date   end.date amount.x   Years.as.customer
    1      C1 01/01/2009 31/12/2009       10   1
    2      C1 01/01/2010 31/12/2010       20   2 
    3      C1 01/01/2011 31/12/2011        5   3
    4      C2 01/01/2009 31/12/2009        7   1
    5      C2 01/01/2010 31/12/2010       12   2
    6      C2 01/01/2011 31/12/2011       11   3
```

I thought this could be achieved by defining a starting date for each company. So if a new name in `df$company` occurs, take the date from `start.date` in the same row and keep it for all rows for the same company in `df$company`. The next step should be to calculate the time difference between the `end.date`s and the starting date. If the difference is <= 1 year, write 1 in `df$years`.
if: 2=> time diff >1 , write year 2 etc.

This should be done for a huge date frame with a different dates (not always exactly 1 year between the two dates and different starting and end dates) and around 3000 companies.

I'm struggling with defining a working function and applying it on the whole data frame.

I hope I could briefly explain the problem and what I want to do about it. Feel free to ask questions if there's anything unclear. I will try to answer them clearly.

Thanks for your help, guys.

Edit: Problems with overlapping years. (@Hugh)

To completely solve my described problems I'm dealing with one last issue:
I used Hugh's solution (see comments) using a combination of the dplyr and lubridate package. See the results written in code below

```
company   start.date  end.date   Years.as.customer
    C20   2010-07-10  2010-09-30  1
    C20   2010-07-10  2011-06-30  2
    C20   2010-07-10  2011-06-30  2
    C20   2010-07-10  2011-06-30  2
    C20   2010-07-10  2011-06-30  2 
    C20   2010-07-10  2011-06-30  2
    C20   2010-10-01  2010-12-31  1
    C20   2011-01-01  2011-03-31  2
    C20   2011-04-01  2011-06-30  2
```

The problem is that company C20 has been a customer for only one year. All dates (from the first date in column start.date to the last date in column end.date) are withing one year if one takes the first row as start.
I guess when the year in column end.date from 2010 to 2011 changes, the value in column Years.as.customer changes from 1 to 2 as well. It should stay at 1 for all given rows since the time interval is still <= 1 year.
Any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couple of questions to clarify your requirements: a) Can a difference between `end.date` and `start.date` be greater than a year? b) What do you want to see for a company that was a client in 2012 and then again in 2014, but not 2013?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: If each row can contain dates from one year only, and dates within each year can be given on one row only, then you may try `with(df, ave(company, company, FUN = seq_along))`.

Comment: Run 'aggregate' on format(start, "%Y") using company as index and length(unique(x)) as a function.

Comment: Thanks for questions.
@Viktor K. : a) The time difference can't be greater than a year.
b) I don't think there any cases like described.. If there are any I think it would be valuable to start with year 1 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this gives what you're after:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df$start.date <- as.Date(df$start.date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
df$end.date <- as.Date(df$end.date, format="%d/%m/%Y")

  df %.% 
  group_by(company) %.% 
  # mutate(Years.as.customer = year(end.date) - min(year(start.date)) + 1)
  mutate(Years.as.customer = 
           ceiling((end.date - min(start.date))/365.25))


# months
library(zoo)
df %.%
  group_by(company) %.%
  mutate(Months.as.customer = as.yearmon(end.date) - min(as.yearmon(start.date)) + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for not coming back earlier.
This is close to what I'm looking for. Thanks for sharing that information with me.
I got two points that I struggle with to get the final solution.
a) For most companies this solutions works perfectly, thank you. For some companies the first row of a new company doesn't start with year 1,  but somehow takes over the value of the last row of the previous company. Any idea what the reason for this could be?
b) Is there a way to do it monthly, instead of adding a whole year? A few time intervals are between two years..
Thanks!

Comment: (a) I'm not entirely sure what you mean here, but if your data isn't accurate, no amount of coding can help that. How do you know the first row of some companies are taken over by the previous row (and not just a coincidence)? (b) Do you mean Months as customer? See my edit if that answers your question.

Comment: See edit of my question for problem (a). That's the last point I'm struggling with. Thanks for everything so far.

Comment: @ Hugh: Thanks for the edit.
The grouping with difftime() works fine except for dates where the years are different in $start.date and $end.date.
If we take for example the following two dates that are the first dates for a Company 20:
2006-07-01(start) 2007-06-30 (end)
The time difference between these two dates is <=365.25 and thus the value in $Years.as.customer should be 1, but it's 2 instead.
This problem occurs whenever the year changes for the entire data frame.
Is ceiling() eventually not the right function?

Thanks for your help, Hugh. Def helps improving my understanding.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot, Hugh!